# Haskell manipulating elements of a list

Tags: list, haskell

So lets say i have a certain string and i want to check the elements of the string, whether they are numbers or characters. Each number has to be replaced with the number 1 and each character with the number 2 and at the end it has to be shown the final result when you sum all numbers.
Example: function "123abc" has to give a result 9

I've already come up with a solution using lists comprehensions and pattern matching, but i need to be able to give a solution without using them, meaning only elem,head,tail,reverse,map,sum etc. All has to be 1 function, now a few combined as one.

Comment: Can you show the solution you’ve come up with, please? It might be easiest to describe how to modify parts of it.

Comment: Please provide your curent attempt.

Comment: Basically i used the isNumber function, importing it from Data.Char and writing it as list comprehention, something like this:  f xs = [if isNumber x then 1 else 2| x <- xs ]

Comment: Shouldn't you `sum` up that list?

Comment: Ups, yeah, here is the full function  f xs = sum([if isNumber x then 1 else 2| x <- xs ])  , but i have to be able to do it without list comprehensions, thats why i asked, if anyone has a possible solution.

Answer (score 6):

You may do as follows;

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)
import Data.Bool (bool)

getsum :: String -> Int
getsum = sum . map (bool 2 1 . isDigit)

*Main> getsum "1234abc"
10
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! One last question - what is the dot used for?

Comment: @zauahiri it's function composition: `f . g` is a function that, applied to `x`, gives `f (g x)`. I.e. in this case, the string is first pulled through the `map`ping, the result of which is then `sum`med.

Comment: @zauahiri `(.)` is the composition operator with type signature `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` which means it takes two function like `f` and `g` and `f . g` works like `f (g (x))`.